# Why can't Nagios start Oracle Database through event handler?

Tags: linux, shell, nagios

I'm trying to start my oracle database as it goes down using an event handler script.

The object configuration file `oraclehost.cfg` has:

```
define host {
host_name                       Test_Oracle
address                         127.0.0.1
check_command                   check-host-alive
check_interval                  3
retry_interval                  1
max_check_attempts              5
check_period                    24x7
process_perf_data               0
retain_nonstatus_information    0
contacts                        nagiosadmin
notifications_enabled           1
notification_interval           30
notification_period             24x7
notification_options            d,r
}
define service {
    host_name               Test_Oracle
    service_description     check_OraDB
    check_command           check_MyOracle
    event_handler           restart-oracle
    event_handler_enabled   1
    check_interval          5
    retry_interval          1
    max_check_attempts      5
    check_period            24x7
    notifications_enabled   1
    notification_interval   30
    notification_period     24x7
    notification_options    r,w,c
    contacts                nagiosadmin
}
```

The `commands.cfg` has:

```
# 'Oracle DB' command definition
define command {
    command_name    check_MyOracle
    command_line    $USER1$/check_oracle_on.sh
}

# 'Oracle DB Handler' command definition
define command {
    command_name    restart-oracle
    command_line    $USER2$/oracle_handle.sh $SERVICESTATE$ $SERVICESTATETYPE$ $SERVICEATTEMPT$
}
```

Here is the `oracle_handle.sh` script that is the event handler script.

```
#!/usr/bin/sh
case "$1" in
OK)
    ;;
WARNING)
    logger "Then it went here"
    PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin:/u/oracle/server/oracle12c102/bin
    export PATH
    ORACLE_HOME=/u/oracle/server/oracle12c102
    export ORACLE_HOME
    ORACLE_SID=walinv
    export ORACLE_SID
    echo "ora123" |sqlplus sys@walinv as sysdba @this_file.sql
    ;;
UNKNOWN)
    ;;
CRITICAL)
    ;;
esac
exit 0
```

The `this_file.sql` contains a single line inside: `startup`.
It is used to start Oracle Database.

Also the `logger "Then it went here"` that is present in the event handler script shows up in the linux logs in `/var/log/messages`. So the `WARNING` case is running.

My Nagios event log shows: [Nagios Event Log Script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWz0x.png)

If I run the script in terminal as `nagios` user, the script runs perfectly and Oracle Database starts. However, if `nagios` runs it through the web server, in the Nagios Web Monitor the state remains in warning and the database is down.

The `nagios` user is in sudoers.

I've wasted more than 10 hours on this. Why is this happening?

Why is Nagios not starting my Oracle Database when it runs the event handler script?

Comment: welcome to U&L, please do not link images when you can paste text.

Comment: and please import a [minimal, complete, verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) version of the script into the Question so that current and future readers can compare/contrast/answer.

Comment: The event handler script that I've provided is the complete script. Also, someone told me that when nagios runs the script through the web, it doesn't have details about ORACLE_HOME and PATH variables which I've mentioned in my /home/.bash_profile. Is this true?

Comment: yep.. you should include them to the even-handler script.

Comment: I've included the PATH and ORACLE_HOME in the event handler script. Still doesn't work...

Comment: Can someone remove it from on-hold. I've provided everything there is and specified everything clearly.

Comment: is the Oracle server running on the Nagios server? the event handler runs on the Nagios server, so if the Oracle server is somewhere else, you'll have to account for that.

Comment: Yes, they are on the same server. I got it to work. Thanks for helping out, all of you.

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work.

The first mistake I did was not exporting the `ORACLE_HOME` and `ORACLE_PATH` in my event handler script.

The second mistake was in this line:

```
echo "ora123" |sqlplus sys@walinv as sysdba @this_file.sql
```

The `this_file.sql` was in the `\usr\local\nagios\libexec\eventhandlers`. When I was executing the script manually from the `eventhandlers` folder, so the `this_file.sql` file was accessible. Nagios doesn't execute it from this folder. When I mentioned the full path and got it to work.